# Better error reporting for Android JUnit4 test runner?

Tags: junit4, android-espresso, android-junit

I am using AndroidJUnit4 as my test runner for android espresso and uiautomator test. The html report generated gives no stack trace information or custom error messages. Is there a way to get detailed report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest